# How can I add additional columns during BULK INSERT without modifying source file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bulk-load

I have a `BULK INSERT` into a table but I need to add data that is not in my csv for the last column in each row of the table.
For example, if my csv file contains 10 columns but the database table contains 11 columns, how can I add data for the last column? Modifying the csv file itself is not an option

Is this possible with `BULK INSERT`?

Here is my script:

```
BULK INSERT [Data_GPS].[dbo].[Data_z]
    FROM 'C:\TEMP\SQL\Bulk insert\dane.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',  
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\TEMP\SQL\Bulk insert\errors.txt',
    TABLOCK
    )
```

Comment: Not directly, no. You'd need to use a staging table.

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Just use [OPENROWSET(BULK ...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/import-bulk-data-by-using-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-bulk-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of BULK INSERT and you can add whatever extra columns you want. EG

```
INSERT INTO dbo.myFirstImport  
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET (
        BULK 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.bcp',
        FORMATFILE = 'D:\BCP\myFirstImport.xml'  
       ) AS t1;
```

But you have to create a [format file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/use-a-format-file-to-bulk-import-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#use-openrowsetbulk-and-xml-format-file) for openrowset.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I read the article but it is too complex for me. I tried for begining 

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\TEMP\SQL\Bulk_insert_posypywarki\dane.csv',SINGLE_CLOB) AS cars;

but in result I got one column and one row and all content of a dane.csv inside a single field. If you pasted here any working script I would be apriciated.

Comment: Getting `A correlation name must be specified for the bulk rowset in the from clause.`.  If I add 'AS X' at the end I get `Either a format file or one of the three options SINGLE_BLOB, SINGLE_CLOB, or SINGLE_NCLOB must be specified.`.